# Call a shell script from Flask API

Tags: python, api, shell, flask, python-3.6

Really new to API building -

I am trying to build an API that will take arguments from the HTTP request. So far I am able to start the flask API server, I have put my script in the same folder. Still, when I call the HTTP URL it is giving me the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"': './bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'
```

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return '''<h1>Shell Run</h1>
<p>An API Call To shell</p>'''


@app.route('/api/v1/bdpaas/resources/', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():

    query_parameters = request.args

    queue = query_parameters.get('queue')
    vcores = query_parameters.get('vcores')
    subprocess.call(['./bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'])

if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run(host='server.mydom.com', debug=True)
```

Running My Code like -

```
python3.6 test_api.py

[ngupta@server:/home/mapr/nishantypython] python3.6 test_api.py
 * Serving Flask app "test_api" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://server.mydom.com:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 266-911-173
10.96.5.176 - - [07/Jul/2020 04:57:29] "GET //api/v1/bdpaas/resources/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mapr/nishantypython/test_api.py", line 47, in api_filter
    subprocess.call(['./bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 287, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"': './bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'
```

```
URL - http://server.mydom.com:5000/api/v1/bdpaas/resources/
```

Any help is appreciated. I might be completely wrong about the concept, Please guide me if that is the case here.

Comment: As of now, using `subprocess.run()` is the [recommended approach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to invoke a subprocess, you might want to refactor the `.call()` except of course you have some compatibility issues

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite explicit. I think the directory is not relative to the app but to where you are running the app from.

To understand better where you are you might want to temporary replace your command with `pwd` or `ls` and see if you're where you want to be.

EDITED:
try with `subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"]).stdout` or `subprocess.run(["pwd"]).stdout` to where is it running the script from.

`subprocess.call` accepts [cwd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api) argument. Once you figure out your path I think you will just have to pass it there.

> If cwd is not None, the function changes the working directory to cwd
> before executing the child. cwd can be a string, bytes or path-like
> object. In particular, the function looks for executable (or for the
> first item in args) relative to cwd if the executable path is a
> relative path.

Comment: This is my dire structure 
[mapr@dbslp0292:/home/mapr/nishantypython] ll
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mapr mapr   43318 Jul  6 15:01 bdp_scheduler_change
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mapr mapr    1731 Jul  7 05:31 test_api.py
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mapr mapr      37 Jul  6 15:09 __pycache__
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mapr mapr      79 Nov  9  2019 templates

Comment: Tried to print the current Dir , but no luck. It doesn't print anything .
`def api_filter():

    query_parameters = request.args

    queue = query_parameters.get('queue')
    vcores = query_parameters.get('vcores')
    home_d = os.system("pwd")
    subprocess.call(['sh bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'])
    return home_d `

Comment: Try writing the absolute path to the script, and maybe there is some special syntax for passing arguments to a shell script in subprocess :)

Comment: @user2910022 I edited my answer. I meant that you should replace your `subprocess` call, not use `os` to check pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of writing `./` to execute your script then write `sh` followed by a space.

```
subprocess.call(['sh bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'])
```

Comment: Hi , I tried to print the Dir by following changes , Please correct me if i am wrong -


def api_filter():
query_parameters = request.args
    queue = query_parameters.get('queue')
    vcores = query_parameters.get('vcores')
    home_d = os.system("pwd")
    subprocess.call(['sh bdp_scheduler_change -q queue -v vcores -s "api" -o "overwrite"'])
    return home_d

Comment: I am running the api script from the same dir -
[mapr@dbslp0292:/home/mapr/nishantypython] ll
total 1704
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mapr mapr     404 Oct 12  2019 1
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mapr mapr   43318 Jul  6 15:01 bdp_scheduler_change
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mapr mapr     790 Oct 14  2019 flaskui.py
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mapr mapr      37 Jul  6 15:09 __pycache__
drwxrwxrwx. 2 mapr mapr      79 Nov  9  2019 templates
-rw-rw-r--. 1 mapr mapr    1731 Jul  7 05:31 test_api.py
drwxrwxr-x. 4 mapr mapr      64 Jun 12 05:06 vm_script1
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 mapr mapr 1687128 Oct 16  2019 vm_script1.zip